# Hide div when clicked on body doesn't work right

Tags: jquery

This is a stupid question, but i can't figure it out, say i have two divs:

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Div one is a button, div two is a box.

Now when i click on div `one` div `two` should be visible (by default it isn't)

And when i click on div `one` one more time div `two` disappears and so on...

Here is my code for that:

```
$(".one").live("click", function(){
    state = $(this).attr("state");

    if(state == "active"){
        $(this).attr("state", "inactive");
        $(".two").css("display", "none");
    }else{
        $(this).attr("state", "active");
        $(".two").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

And now my problem is that i also want div `two` disappear when i click anywhere in my page so this is what i did:

```
$(document).click(function(){
     $(".one").attr("state", "inactive");
     $(".two").css("display", "none");
});
```

Now what happens is probably click event on document happens after the click on div and it doesn't let me open box.

One solution that i know is to check if `(event.target.className != "one")` but i would really like to avoid that since in my real project i have a lot of other elements in that button so i would need to include all of them, and i would like to avoid that.

Comment: I guess checking is necessary. Instead of a direct check, you may perhaps use the jquery not() in your selector : http://api.jquery.com/not/ and btw $(".two").css("display", "none") == $(".two").hide()

Comment: `$(".two").toggle()` would do the same trick?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. For newer versions you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6SngB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return false;` from the bound `.live()` handler.  You want to stop event propagation and that is the way to break the chain for live events (which have already bubbled).